RS232: How are start/stop bits identified and not in character of data?
In RS232 serial communication as pictured below how does one ensure the bit stream is always read at the start/stop bits? I’m looking at this waveform and considering a case where two consecutive differing characters have start/stop bits in them n clocks apart and could be mistaken for start/stop shifting the entire stream. I was thinking maybe the low idle should be longer in duration then the 8 + 1 clocks to identify the start but am not sure. I was also thinking maybe the parity bit could be used to eliminate some error reading from the wrong start position.
Can anyone explain how this case is excluded and proper bit stream aligned?

Image source: Anticyclone Systems - An introduction to RS232 serial port communication

sample the data at 8x the baud rate, or higher ... reset the counter whenever the data transition occurs ... shift in data at center of bit

Nick - Hi, Your question seems to be a different way of asking the same as asked in these 2 questions: "How does UART know the difference between data bits and start/stop bits?", "Detecting start bit in software UART" and in this answer to a different question. What do you think? Do they help?

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you're concerned about a "Sync Error"... i.e: the device becomes "aware" part way through a frame, and then incorrectly decodes what it thinks "looks like" a frame:

This is difficult to intrinsically protect against at the UART level, but there are a few things that can help:

Inter-Frame Gap: by allowing the line to idle periodically, the devices may regain synchronisation due to that extended idle period. Protocols like Modbus RTU actually use the inter-frame gap for framing the received message.
Parity Bit: by enabling the parity bit, it's more likely (but not guaranteed) that a sync error like this will be detected
Robust Protocol: you can get better confidence in the recieved data by including start-of-frame markers, checksums, and other features in your protocol - if it doesn't match your expectations, then discard the frame and try again.
Recieve Errors: the UART peripherals will often inform you of errors encountered during the recieve - framing, parity, etc... When these occur, take corrective action in your firmware (e.g: by discarding the current packet). This level of detail is often ignored in firmware, and may not even be exposed by your HAL / OS.
Extended Idle on Startup: wait for the line to idle for at least n bit-times before allowing recieve. I don't know if this is commonly implemented in UART peripherals (it may well be, but it's also easy to accidentally omit from custom gateware!) and it may cause issues with particularly high-utilization connections. In this case, "becoming aware" half way through the bit-time wouldn't permit the marked "start" to be considered a trusted start, because the preceeding idle wasn't long enough.

Note that in the example above, we might see valid data with no framing errors!

Valid 0x09 frame
Valid 0x0D frame
Valid 0xFF frame (maybe... what would be the stop-bit is off-screen)


If the line was idle for 10 or more bit times, the first edge is the start bit. If the receiver starts listening in the middle of an ongoing transmission, there is indeed a risk of "false lock" with some data patterns. Most high-level protocols that build on RS-232 use short packets with checksums and some idle time between packets. This is enough to mitigate the problem in practice.
The idle time between packets also serves as a delimiter and triggers a software interrupt on most receivers, which forces a flush of the receive queue. On Linux and many other operating systems, the interrupt itself is not exposed to the user, but flushing the queue makes a blocking read return immediately (with fewer bytes read than the programmer had requested.) The programmer requests a blocking read with more bytes than the longest possible packet, knowing that the read will return with fewer bytes as soon as the packet has ended and the line has returned to idle. On a microcontroller, the programmer can directly hook into the idle interrupt.
When creating a protocol on top of an RS-232 link, define a maximum packet length and leave the line idle for a short time (> 40 bit times is typical) between packets. This idle time is needed both for hardware synchronization (unambiguous start bit, as per your question) and for packet synchronization in software (early return of blocking read.) An example of such high-level protcol is MODBUS RTU (see MODBUS over Serial Line Specification and Implementation Guide), which specifies a maximum frame size of 256 characters, an inter-frame delay of >3.5 characters and a 16 bit CRC. The relevant information is on page 13 of the document, or in the image below:

Your idea of "Extended Idle on Startup" can be easily implemented from user space and works with most, if not all, receivers. After program start, perform a single blocking read with more bytes than the longest possible packet, then throw it away. The next read is guaranteed to align with a packet boundary and does not suffer from false lock. The only requirements are that your high-level protocol has a maximum packet size and some idle time between packets. If your protocol has a CRC checksum, you don't need to special-case the first read. It will be thrown away automatically for failing the CRC test.

Helpful explanation! What higher level protocols may be considered to improve on this? Also the extended idle time, is this practice of causing it between n frames start/stop implemented in practice?

@Nick See MODBUS over Serial Line Specification and Implementation Guide for an example of a higher-level protocol. Modbus RTU was also mentioned in the other answer

tl;dr: Assume the line starts from idle. The receive process starts at the leading edge of the start bit, and lasts until the stop bit, at which point the receiver reverts to looking for start. As long as the baud rates and formats agree, another receive won’t begin until another start bit happens. If that’s not the case, the receiver could see a false start, resulting in a mangled receive and/or a framing error.
First, let's get the polarities straight. As below:

(from here: http://www.dragonwins.com/domains/getteched/de248/rs232.htm)
RS-232 defines two levels: 'mark' (logical 1) and 'space' (logical 0). The RS-232 to TTL converter inverts these to/from the UART, so 'mark' is high at the UART and 'space' is low.
The UART framing state machine starts out by looking for the leading edge of the start bit, which is always a mark-to-space  transition (high to low at the UART.) Once the UART sees this, its state machine starts counting out the bits and sampling each one.
At the end of the frame is the stop bit, which is always a logical 1 'mark' (high at the UART.) We'll come back to why that is in a moment. At this point the data bits are received, the UART state machine dispatches the received byte to the receive FIFO and goes back to looking for a start bit. The receiver is self-resetting.
Remember I said that the stop bit is always a logical 1? When data frames are sent back-to-back, the frame-to-frame 'gap' is in fact the stop bit. That ensures that there will always be a mark-to-space transition (high to low at the UART) for the UART to re-establish framing.
And in fact you can have as many stop bits as you like. You can even let the line go idle (sit in mark state) for an extended time. The UART patiently waits for the next start bit to sync things back up for the frame that follows.
An example: a terminal session will send bytes keystroke-by-keystroke, so there will be long idle periods in between. In contrast, the host can send data back at full speed with no idle, with the frames separated only by stop bits.
In other words, the time between frames is at least one stop bit, but can be any asynchronous length of time (that is, idle period) greater than or equal to the stop bit time.
It’s entirely possible for the state machine to get out of sync and mis-frame the data. This can happen if some signal corruption occurred, the more more likely cause is that the baud rates or frame formats didn’t agree.
The UART can detect this in a couple of ways: it sees a that a stop bit is non-zero (framing error), or parity doesn’t match (parity error).

I’m curious about the extended idle state. It seems this extended time, longer then 9 bit lengths could establish the start of the frame better then parity bit. Is this implemented and does it occur after so many frames periodically?

The character-to-character timing of depends entirely on the sender. For example, someone tapping at a keyboard will send characters infrequently, with variable time between keystrokes. The machine can respond with a screenful of data with no pauses  at all (other than the stop bits.) it simply does not matter: as long as the data aren’t corrupted the receiver on each side will see the start bit and fire up the state machine to grab the bits.

Break, I think I missed that. What is the definition

At any rate the receiver state machine is guaranteed to reach the ‘looking for start’ state after 9 or 10 baud times.

A break is the line going ‘space’ state for some number of milliseconds (I forget, maybe 250?) An Rs-232 receiver that’s not physically connected will be in this state by default.

@hacktastical incorrect, an RS-232 receiver with nothing connected will idle at logic '1' level. And simple UARTs that receives a BREAK will simply see that stop bit was incorrect, marking the received frame with Framing Error. Technically these cannot determine if BREAK was started during a data frame (data is non-zero with framing error) or from idle state (break causes 0x00 data and framing error).

@justme - you're right. A disconnected MC1489 will default to 'mark', same as idle. A break is initiated by the sender, which is seen as a long period of 'space' (low at the UART RxD). The UART RX will see this as a framing error, and may additionally have break detection as a separate function (e.g., detect 'space' for a long time. Example: https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/oxy/GUID-F2693295-804D-4E36-8BA5-0105C1751EA5-en-US-3/GUID-B1FEB099-3B32-462D-AA49-3FA800650662.html)

The simple answer is, the receiver knows how many bits to sample in the frame after seeing edge of a start bit. The start bit begins with an edge to start the frame reception if you are not currently receiving a frame. When receiving a frame and  sampling of those data bits and the stop bit is complete, the frame reception ends. Then the line either stays idle for any amount of time or there an edge for the next start bit right after the previous stop bit, which again starts the frame reception.
To put things into context, notice that RS-232 is only an electrical protocol for a physical interface that defines only logic levels and rough limits for data rate, the RS-232 does not take any part in what protocol to use for sending data and how, so the question is not about RS-232 itself, but something else.
Your question is about asynchronous start-stop protocol, a protocol how to send data in frames delimited by start and stop bits, often implemented with an UART, and often used with physical interfaces such as RS-232 or RS-485.
Simplified version is that initially the UART is idle, not receiving a data frame, and waiting for a data frame to start, i.e. waiting until there is a transition on the wire, to detect the edge of the start bit.
After edge of start bit is detected, it will receive the whole frame by sampling all the bits in at the pre-defined bit rate. The stop bit is the last bit in the frame and then the frame reception is finished, and UART goes to idle state, to wait for the start bit edge of the next frame.
There might be no idle time at all between stop and start bit, so the next start bit will be determined again correctly from the next edge after stop bit. But there can also be any amount of idle time between stop bit and the following start bit.
In fact the start bit detection starts right after determining that stop bit is correctly received, this will allow for slight tolerance in the bit rates that the devices use. In theory, both devices only need to be within about 1% of the nominal baud rate and depending on a lot of factors, more or less tolerance is allowed.
This is why the bit rate and the format of the frame must be predefined so that the receiver can correctly receive it. This includes number of data bits, possibly followed by a parity bit which the UART can check for you, so the UART must know how many bits of data to expect before parity, and to check if the stop bit is also correct or if there is a framing error.
Yes, there are bit patterns that could get synchronized incorrectly. For example a continuous stream of 0x55 sent at 8N1 framing is just square wave on the wire, so if UART cable is unplugged and replugged in the middle of such a stream, the receiver will just detect the first edge as beginning of start bit even if it might not be, and receive all frames incorrectly, unless there later is a long enough delay or suitable data pattern like 0xFF injected to allow resynchronization of framing.
